# Block matrix determinant with symmetrically placed blocks

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I am trying to solve the determinant of the following block matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}A-Ia&B\\B &A-Ib \end{bmatrix}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $I$ is an identity matrix. Matrices $A$ and $B$ are square.

Unfortunately, I can't invoke the general expression since I don't want to attempt to invert any of these matrices (very complex). I see from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) that

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B &A \end{bmatrix} = \det(A+B)\det(A-B)$$ Can anyone help me prove that this can be applied to my matrix (Such that I might get something like $\det(A-Ia+B)\det(A-Ib-B)$)? Or alternatively, can anyone solve the determinant of my matrix without taking an inverse?

Thanks!

Comment: If "something like $\det(A-Ia+B)\det(A-Ib-B)$" means a product of nontrivial factors, then it's unlikely to exist, since the determinant of your matrix is an irreducible polynomial when $A$ and $B$ are $1\times 1$-matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof for the Wikipedia formula was given in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117072/blockwise-symmetric-matrix-determinant), which unfortunately still leads to a system for which an inverse needs to be taken in order to solve the determinant. At least I was able to prove that in this general case it's impossible:

Inserting my matrix into the proof for \begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B &A \end{bmatrix}

Gives

$$\begin{bmatrix}I&-I\\0 &I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A-Ia&B\\B &A-Ib \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}I&I\\0 &I \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A-Ib-B&Ib-Ia\\B &A-Ib+B \end{bmatrix}$$

Which still requires an inverse to solve, given that none of the appropriate sub-matrices commute.

Comment: @ Stuart Barth , five days ago, Farhad gives, in his answer , a generalization of the result mentioned in the thread above (dated $2$ days ago). Finally, Stuart gives the green chevron to..... Stuart. Fortunately,  the ridiculous does not kill. Moreover, you write  "At least I was able to prove that in this general case it's impossible."  I eagerly await your proof.

Comment: As I indicated, Farhad's response is specifically not what I asked for. In order to know that I can't apply the wikipedia formula, I needed to know how to prove it. I've now added above the important part of this disproof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
If $(A-aI)$ be invertible then
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}A-Ia&B\\B &A-Ib \end{bmatrix}=\det(A-aI)\det(A-bI-B(A-aI)^{-1}B)$$

Comment: Thanks, but as I indicated in my original post, I am looking for a solution that does not require taking an inverse - this formulation is what I referred to as the "general expression".